# How do you use braces with execlp()?

Tags: c, exec, parentheses

My program works when I use `execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", NULL)` but it doesn't work when I do `execlp("{", "{", "ls", "-al", "}", NULL)`

Is there a way to use braces with `execlp()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the answer is no.

```
execlp("{", "{", "ls", "-al", "}", NULL)
```

You're trying to execute a command named `{`.  `{` is not a command; it's part of the shell's syntax, and `execlp` (unlike `system`) doesn't execute its command via the shell. The command name has to be an actual executable (binary or shell script).

If you really want to do that, you can invoke `/bin/sh` as the command, and pass command-line arguments that it will then execute.  For example (I haven't tested this):

```
execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "{ ls -al; }", NULL);
```

Note that the entire command is a single string, which `/bin/sh` treats an an argument to the `-c` option. (The shell itself will then split it into words.)

Comment: Note that in this context, the braces provide no benefit.  In a shell script, they provide a unit for I/O redirection, but the embedded shell script here contains no I/O redirection.

Comment: Also (and just for fun), note that `execlp("[", "[", "ls", "-gt", ".", "]", NULL);` would probably work and might even succeed (but wouldn't produce any output).  But that's because there usually is a binary `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` for `execlp()` to execute.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about '[' in /bin or /usr/bin. What is that about?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: For this particular case, yes, I'm assuming that this is a simplified example. (Though whatever the OP is trying to do might be accomplished more easily by writing and invoking a shell script rather than constructing shell syntax in memory.)

Comment: @CharlieBurns: `[` is a command, nearly equivalent to `test`. Unlike `{`, it's not built-in shell syntax. `info bash` or `info test` for more information.